# Слайдер OwlCarousel обрезает фотографии

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

[image: Фотки обрезаются]

На сайте установлен слайдер owlCarousel. Такая проблема: фотки на слайдере обрезаются, как на фото. При ресайзе окна всё становится норм. Если перезагрузить страницу, то иногда тоже становится норм, через раз. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Подскажите, что делать

Comment: Будьте добры, приложите код разметки, стилей и скрипта, которые затрагивают данный слайдер.

Comment: soho-bridge.ru, это сам сайт

Comment: не охота ванговать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-lg-14 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%; // щас меньше 100%
}
```